# Class on click not working JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im working on a sidebar what must be smaller if I click on a system button. So my plan is to add classes to different div's to adjust the style so it will become smaller etc.

Unfortunately my code is not working. I've tried it with a simple class with display none, but if I click on the class it will not apply the css. Here is my code:

```
<aside>
    <h2 class="menu-head-text">Menu options</h2>
    <a href="#" class="menu-size">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="nieuwewall.html"><i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i><span class="menu-item-text">Overzicht wall</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="nieuwewall.html"><i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i><span class="menu-item-text">Betaalgegevens</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</aside>
```

```js
$(function() {
    $(".menu-size").click(function() {
        $(".menu-item-text").addClass(".display");
    });
});
```

```css
.display {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Hope somebody can help me out. Thanks in advance

Comment: `addClass("display")`, You have prefixed `.`, just need to pass class name

Comment: no need to add `.` on addClass and removeClass

Comment: Remove the dot on display className. `$('selector').addClass('display')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one. Remove the `.` in the `display`

```
$(function() { //run when the DOM is ready
    $(".menu-size").click(function() { //use a class, since your ID gets mangled
        $(".menu-item-text").addClass("display"); //add the class to the clicked element
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Above answers is correct, but its better to add one css class to main element (aside on your excample), then make css to children element by css classes nesting.

Check out this jsfiddle: 
HTML:

```
<aside>
  <h2 class="menu-head-text">Menu options</h2>
  <a href="#" class="menu-size"><i class="fa fa-bars">XXX</i></a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="nieuwewall.html"><i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i><span class="menu-item-text">Overzicht wall</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="nieuwewall.html"><i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i><span class="menu-item-text">Betaalgegevens</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</aside>
```

CSS:

```
aside {
  background-color: red; 
}

aside.smaller {
  background-color: blue; 
}

aside.smaller * {
  font-size: .8rem;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $(".menu-size").click(function() {
        $("aside").addClass("smaller");
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/LLu4tra9/